# Data is not being passed correctly via props React

Tags: reactjs

Tell me please

Why the data passed through props does not change when it is changed in useLocation()

1. I have data transfer via Link

   ```
   <Link
     to={{
     pathname: '/catalog/product_card/' + product.id,
     state: { product }
   }}>
     <span className="product-name">{product.name}</span>
   </Link>
   ```
2. I get them via useLocation in ProductCardView

   ```
   const CategoryViewDesktop = ({productState}:any) => {
     const product = productState.product;

     console.log(product)
     return (
       <div>{product.id}</div>
     )
   }

   const ProductCardView = () => {
     const { state } = useLocation()
     const productState = {products: state.products, product: state.product}

     console.log(state.product)
     return (
       <Page page="catalog.products">
           <CategoryViewDesktop productState={productState} />
       </Page>
     )
   }
   ```
3. In ProductCardView - data changes when interacting with Link, but the same data comes to ProductCardInfo

Why is this and how to fix it?

Comment: Don't post code as image. Copy and paste the code within the post itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, where is the `product` object passed in route state being changed? Where are you expecting to see the changes? What is `ProductCardInfo` component? Is that relevant to the issue? What is `Data` that is being passed as a prop?

Comment: 1 code snippet - displays a link to a separate product card, when you click on it, the data goes in the ProductCardView component - I get them through useLocation()
then this data goes to ProductCardInfo, where I display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your variable `productState` is not reactive, you can use hook `useState` or use `useLocation` state directly on child component props .

```
  const CategoryViewDesktop = ({productState}:any) => {
        const product = productState.product;
        
        console.log(product)
        return (
            <div>{product.id}</div>
        )
    }
    
    const ProductCardView = () => {
        const { state } = useLocation()
    
        console.log(state.product)
        return (
            <Page page="catalog.products">
                <CategoryViewDesktop productState={state} />
            </Page>
        )
    }
```